Angular front-end deployed in Azure can't connect to back-end API, the api url is spliced
I have deployed Spring boot backend and Angular frontend website in Azure, when I access the website, for some reason the frontend url is spliced in front of the api url causing me to be unable to access it. My local development environment is all fine.
As shown below, Brower got the wrong API URL https://ambitious-ground-04bd38a0f.5.azurestaticapps.net/ecommercespring-g7guhdcvf2gjgrd6.canadaeast-01.azurewebsites. net/api/product-category

My correct API URL should be https://ecommercespring-g7guhdcvf2gjgrd6.canadaeast-01.azurewebsites.net/api

And I don't think I have a problem with Angular's Cors.
Below are my Angular Cors URL setting



If possible, share your GitHub repository?

@Wenbo Peng  Looks like environment prod values are loaded correctly. Please refer this link. If apiBaseUrl is empty it will take default front end url.

@AsleshaKantamsetti Hello, below are my backend and frontend repos
https://github.com/pwbhs/eCommerceApp
https://github.com/pwbhs/eCommerceAngular

It should be an https:// in front of the API URL :)

It might be due to the base url not having http:// or https:// infront of the link, try setting the ApiBaseUrl to :
https://ecommercespring-g7guhdcvf2gjgrd6.canadaeast-01.azurewebsites.net/api
or
http://ecommercespring-g7guhdcvf2gjgrd6.canadaeast-01.azurewebsites.net/api

Thank you! Add https:// in front of the backend API URL and everything works fine.
